# Trying to load fbx on THREE.js getting ReferenceError: "url is not defined"

Tags: three.js, fbx

Im trying to load a fbx exported in version: FBX 6.1 ASCII
And im getting "url is not defined" error, when i load xsi_man_skinning.fbx from THREE.js examples it works, so i think it's related to blender export plugin, could someone point me to how or what to use to export a THREE.js compatible fbx file?

Comment: post some code, the error you are getting is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

It's not super clear without looking at the FBXLoader source code, but it looks like the FBX version needs to be above 7.0:

```
 * Loader loads FBX file and generates Group representing FBX scene.
 * Requires FBX file to be >= 7.0 and in ASCII or >= 6400 in Binary format
 * Versions lower than this may load but will probably have error
```

[Here's](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js#L6) the line with the comment.

I'd try exporting with a newer version. Hope that helps!

Comment: not sure how this would product an error `url is not defined`

Comment: I was reading quickly and interpreted that as a `url === undefined` type of error, but you're right, `url is not defined` is different. It would be easier to help with more details.